# android binder service - maximum allowed concurrent transactions?

Tags: android, android-service

Does anyone know what's the maximum number of transactions which android binder service (local or remote) can handle?

I referred Google docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

It only says that it has the capability of handling simultaneous requests, but not really talks about the maximum number of simultaneous transactions allowed.

Comment: http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/native/libs/binder/ProcessState.cpp#325

Answer (score 1):

you can perform any no of transactions with binder service, there no any kind of limit. its a background service that is bind with a view by binder interface, view can perform any no of transactions with service.